# Is it possible to use lambda/linq with await on getting a collection?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, async-await

I've been using a lot of Async lately because the client application is a mobile app and it's important to use non ui blocking api.

I've been doing queries like this:

```
var answer = _baseCommands.GetAll<Answer>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionId == question1.QuestionId && x.IsCorrect);
```

Which is this method but I also use this as well:

```
 IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : class;
 Task<IQueryable<T>> GetAllAsync<T>() where T : class;
```

This is the implementation for both in BaseCommands:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>()
            where T : class
        {
            return _askDatabase.Set<T>();
        }

        public async Task<IQueryable<T>> GetAllAsync<T>()
            where T : class
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(_askDatabase.Set<T>());
        }
```

Is there anyway to write code like this so I can get all aysnc but with a lambda:

```
 var answer = await _baseCommands.GetAllAsync<Answer>().Result.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionId == question1.QuestionId && x.IsCorrect);
```

What's good practise for this?

Comment: It seems unlikely that your `GetAllAsync` actually does what you want. After all, creating an `IQueryable` is probably cheap - it's not going to *execute* the query. You want something that will make the execution part asynchronous. We don't know what your `IQueryable<T>` implementation is, which makes it harder to help you too...

Comment: @JonSkeet GetAllAsync from what I can see just creates a new task which is awaited. I guess what I want is the best from both worlds. I want to use Async because we're developing mobile apps but I just want a single query on the collection as well. To get all records and then filter it seems more inefficient unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Yes, the task can be awaited - but that will only get you an `IQueryable<T>`. No work will have been performed - so why bother making it asynchronous? You want the *query execution* to be asynchronous.

Comment: @JonSkeet The answer that springs to mind is on the front end, we await api calls which are async task<IHttpActionResult> and without that, the user experience would be worse. I don't have a better answer than that for the overall inclusion of using async.

Comment: Well yes, you should definitely be asynchronous from the client side. But we don't know where the code you've provided sits - whether you've got some kind of `IQueryable<T>` that can be returned to the client, or whether that's your server-side code. There's a lot in this question which is unclear, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronously creating an `IQueryable<T>` doesn't make much sense to be honest. The created object is simply representing the *question*, it's not executing the query itself, so it's probably very cheap; remember LINQ is lazy; the query will be executed when you enumerate over it, not before.

An asynchronous approach would make much more sense if you return an enumerated query, calling, for example, `ToList()`. This could make sense if the connection has very high latency and the amount of data you are bringing back form the DB is not excessively big.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible by wrapping it with `()`:

```
(await _baseCommands.GetAllAsync<Answer>())
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionId == question1.QuestionId && x.IsCorrect);
```

### Explanation:

`await _baseCommands.GetAllAsync<Answer>().FirstOrDefault` doesn't compile because Task doesn't have a definition for that method. But if you wrap that await call in `()`, then you can execute the `.FirstOrDefault` on the result of that task. Note that this executes the filtering `synchronously`.

### Side Notes on your code:

Using  `Task.FromResult` is useless in your API, you're not doing things asynchronously here. This is used mainly for mock-ups. You need to use `Task.Run()` instead in order to execute the query Asynchronously.  Also, you'd better execute the query and return a Collection using `.ToList()` in order to execute the query in the background thread.

If you can change the API that fetches the data, I do advise you to add some overloads:

```
Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class;
```

Then you can use that predicate to query the database directly inside the API.

Comment: So you would recommend that I add the overload?

Comment: @nickgowdy Yes, that way to can filter the data using the API directly through the database and using background threads instead of filtering in your calling code.

Comment: @nickgowdy also using `return await Task.FromResult` is useless in your case, you can use `return Task.FromResult` only because you're awaiting the task in the calling method. Although as stated in my code using `Task.FromResult` is completely opposite to what you're trying to do and you should consider using `Task.Run`